# Understanding Megillah 3a

Tags: death, melachim-kings-book-of, tractate-megillah, zecharia-book-of, targumin

The gemarah megillah 3a expalians that were it not for the targum we would not understand the verse in Zecharya 12:11 which says there on that day the mourning in Jerusalem was like the mourning of Hadadrimon in the valley of Miggido. The targum explains that the pasuk is referring to the mourning for King Achav who was killed by Hadadrimon.

1. Where does it say that there was any mourning (especially a great one) for king Achav?
2. Rashi on Melachim alef 22:34 indicates that the man who killed Achav was Naaman. Is he arguing on the targum?

Comment: Great question! Note, however, that the Targum actually provides two interpretations, not one: the mourning of Hadadrimon in Megiddo corresponds to the death of Ahab (killed by Hadadrimon) and also to the death of Josiah (killed in Megiddo). Note also that Rashi (Zech 12:11) says exactly the same thing.

Comment: "Where does it say that there was any mourning (especially a great one) for king Achav?" Why do you assume this is states anywhere? Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Turei Even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Leib_ben_Asher_Gunzberg) to Megillah (3a) writes that either there are simply contradictory views about who killed Ahav, or Hadadrimon and Naaman are the same person. See also S'fat Emmet there.

Regarding the context of interpreting the mourning as referring to Ahav, although the Bible doesn't reference his mourning, see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=LDLkA9ks3OoC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=bible%20mourning%20for%20ahab&source=bl&ots=Tz9pSDjOYE&sig=eGtngUoksyFYBd7Z2kT_u8GcEao&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiggeSExbTXAhVM94MKHcKODZkQ6AEIWTAL#v=onepage&q=bible%20mourning%20for%20ahab&f=false).